# Add array in Redux to empty Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, react-native, redux

How do I put data into "data" when I first move to the screen. It only works when entering a value in the search box.

This is my code:

```
  const resData = useSelector(state => state.products.products);
  const [data, setData] = useState(resData);
```

Search function

```
const SearchFilterFunction = text => {
    const newData = resData.filter(item => {
      const itemData = item.productName
        ? item.productName.toUpperCase()
        : ''.toUpperCase();
      const textData = text.toUpperCase();
      return itemData.indexOf(textData) > -1;
    });
    setData(newData);
    setText(text);
  };
```

And TextInput & Flatlist

```
      <TextInput
        // style={styles.textInputStyle}
        onChangeText={text => SearchFilterFunction(text)}
        value={text}
        underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
        placeholder="Search Here"
      />
      <FlatList
        data={data}
```

Comment: What value do you have in `resData`?

Comment: It's an array..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest to use [`useEffect`](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html) hook to catch `resData` changes. By passing `resData` into the dependency array you achieve to call `setData` when `resData` is changing.

Try as the following:

```
const resData = useSelector(state => state.products.products);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   setData(resData);
}, [resData]);
```

I hope this helps!